# I want to get data from a list intro hashmap in MongoDB - Java

Tags: java, mongodb

Structure hashmap

```
private Map<Phone, List<Address>> phones;
```

Phone and Address is a class.

Class Phone

```
private String number;
```

Class Address

```
private String street;
private String nrodoor;
```

example data

```
{
  "_id" : "52337346e4b0c8074b67808f",
  "name" : "Pepe",
  "phones" : {
    "123456" : [{
        "street" : "Address 1",
        "nrodoor" : "1040"
      }, {
        "street" : "Address 2",
        "nrodoor" : "3143"
      }]
  },
  "comment" : "Java"
}
```

I want to do a search for the phones field filtering by the value.

such phones "123456"

to recover the complete object.

Someone could help me.

Comment: Could you show us your attempts? It's not clear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to test for the existence of the filed "phones.123456".
I tried this in the console:

```
db.test.insert({ a: "hello" })
db.test.insert({ a: { b: "hello" }})
db.test.find({ "a.b" : { $exists: true }})
```

I get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5233f7e8e4600dc4e40965c4"), "a" : { "b" : "hello" } }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfect.